# Stream audio on Mac

Tags: macos, audio, audio-streaming

I have been using AVAudioPlayer on the iPhone and iPad.  I can't find anything that comes close on the Mac.  Does anyone know where to find a library like that ?

What I want is a library that can stream songs from the internet so the user does not need to download the whole song.

NSSound can play songs from the internet but it does not stream, it just downloads the song and starts to play.

Answer (score 0):

I know ffmpeg works on the Mac and supports streaming.  As an added bonus, it works on Linux and Windows too.

Comment: ffmpeg has nothing to do with the question

Comment: I disagree, ffmpeg is a library you can integrate with your app which do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

[Matt Gallagher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36103/matt-gallagher) has a [series of articles](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/streaming-mp3aac-audio-again.html) on his website regarding this, streaming audio on the iPhone and on the Mac as well. He has this project [posted on github](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) as well.

It's pretty popular and I've personally used it on an iPhone project and it worked well. It comes with an included Mac sample project which also works well.

Comment: The example does not work on the Mac (10.6) and I was looking at something simpler